# RecyclerView should not have too many items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Please do not question the 'why' of this issue. I ran into it while prototyping some stuff, so will probably never end up in a released version.
But that the crash occurred, troubled me.

I use `RecyclerView` with a horizontal oriented `LinearLayoutManager`.

I wanted to create a huge adapter, unlimited amount of items. So what I did was:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

and to reuse the items:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    position = position % (items.size() - 1);
    ...
    // set the data
    ...
```

I have multiple `RecyclerView` in the layout btw, just FYI.

What happens next is, that the app hangs on startup, and finally throws this stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3296): java.lang.StackOverflowError
E/AndroidRuntime( 3296):    at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper$Bucket.insert(ChildHelper.java:411)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3296):    at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper$Bucket.insert(ChildHelper.java:401)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3296):    at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper$Bucket.insert(ChildHelper.java:401)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3296):    at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper$Bucket.insert(ChildHelper.java:401)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3296):    at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper$Bucket.insert(ChildHelper.java:401)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3296):    at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper$Bucket.insert(ChildHelper.java:401)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3296):    at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper$Bucket.insert(ChildHelper.java:401)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3296):    at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper$Bucket.insert(ChildHelper.java:401)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3296):    at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper$Bucket.insert(ChildHelper.java:401)
...
```

It should not mather how many items you have in the adapter, but some how, this is too many. Is there some prework being done for each item?

Comment: IMO, your mistake is using `return Integer.MAX_VALUE;` because theoretically you want the list to have huge amount of items, but `currently` it does not, while `getCount()` should return CURRENT count of items in the adapter, not the `to be` count

Comment: @Yazan I'm trying to get something like endless looping list. I faked it by make it enormous and do a modulo when filling the ViewHolder. And still: why does the stackoverflow occur? Not sure what you mean with your comment

Comment: i said theoretically, because you may get an `OutOfMemoryException` before adding a `Integer.MAX_VALUE` items to the adapter, so this value may never return by `getCount()`, so did you add Integer.MAX_VALUE items in the adapter, i think the answer is No, so you need to add items to the adapter, try to get a close count to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and let `getCount()` return whatever values count you have.

Comment: maybe not adding items at once helps? like 100 items at once, and then when the user scrolls, 100 more..

Comment: @Boy what you have done now is like making a party, you planned to invite 1000 person, now the party did not even begin, you can't say i have a 1000 person in the party now, because no one has arrived yet, even if the party begin, you will have count = 0 and goes up as people start to arrive, then it may and may NOT hit the 1000.

Comment: I do not get your points...an adapter gets items on request. So actually, I'm telling there are MAX_INT items..and then the RecyclerView (or as ListView also does) would say: "ok, user is seeing item 0, so get item 0 and fill the data...now item 1...". It should not even think of any items that are not visible to the user yet...

Comment: @Boy try this simplest adapter : http://pastebin.com/FN061jKi

Comment: @pskink what is the difference with how I'm doing it?

Comment: @Boy i don't know: i posted the full adapter's working code, you didn't

Comment: OK, I tried your code in mine and it gives no crash. I'll have to do some more research what exactly is the difference...

Comment: @Boy have you solved your problem? I've run into the same issue, using 25.1.1 support library but only on API 19. Still working fine on latest version of sdk.

Comment: @AlexIvanov I don't have the issue anymore, but I don't remember what it was, sorry.

Comment: @Boy thank you for reply anyways

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I reproduced it only on KitKat. My view contains `RecyclerView` with huge adapter (Integer.MAX_VALUE) to implement some kind of infinite scrolling. On KitKat I had `StackOverflowError` with same stacktrace. I noticed that this error happened only if my `RecyclerView` was wrapped with `FrameLayout` with `layout_weight=0`. So I just rewrote my view to get rid of this `FrameLayout` and everything works ok now. I don't know exactly reason why it happened and why it happened only on Kitkat, but I think it related to view sizes measuring. Hope it will help.